# Declaring a JNDI variable in JBoss 4.0.5

Tags: jboss, jndi

I want to declare a new JNDI variable in the JBoss 4.0.5 server. Can someone please explain how this can be done?

waiting for your replies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found these two links that can help...

create a file called filename-service.xml under $CATALINA_BASE$/deploy directory with contents as indicated in these links

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/Additional_Naming_MBeans-JNDI_Binding_Manager.html

check a jboss jira, JBPAPP-2809 for correction in xmlns:jndi

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/j2eeguide/r2/en/html/ch3.chapter.html) and specifically [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/j2eeguide/r2/en/html/ch3.chapter.html#ch3.j2ee). You need to add an entry in the ejb-jar.xml file of your application.

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know where is this context.xml is placed?

because, in the link you gave, it is specified that the context.xml present in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml but, I' not able to find this file in my Jboss. (it's inside default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar folder)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this probelm too today. Looks like to add a simple jndi entry on the app server, in JBoss one will have to create a new file  $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml and invoke a MBean to add the variable and its value.

In server like websphere you can pass new values in jndi.properties, which jboss 5.0.0 upwards does not like.

Very Bad that there is absolutely NO DOCUMENTATION in jboss/docs that indicate anything on this topic.